# Unable to access jarfile from docker run command for java maven project

Tags: java, maven, docker

Build docker images using docker file for maven project

When try running docker run getting error saying Unable to access jarfile.

Can some one assist on whats wrong with .

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine as release
RUN addgroup -g 1001 -S user1 && user1 -u 1001 -S user1 -G user1
WORKDIR /home/app
COPY --from=builder /home/app/service-1.0.0.jar .
RUN chown -R user1:user1 /home/app
USER user1
ENTRYPOINT  ["java", "-jar" ,"/home/app/service-1.0.0.jar"]
```

but when i go for docker run with local config files as build mount

```
docker run -it --mount type=bind,source=D:/Java/service/docker/config,target=/home/app services
```

> Unable to access jarfile /home/app/service-1.0.0.jar

Can someone assist on this or is something wrong i did??

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are looking for multistage docker build. If not, you need not use "COPY --from=builder" as it tires to copy the build artifact from your previous stage to this new stage. If it is a single stage docker build, you might just use the copy as follows -

COPY /home/app/service-1.0.0.jar .

Comment: It’s a multistage build so I have used “COPY—from=builder”

Answer (score 0):

Able to resolve the same, Issue was due to mound of config files not happened properly.

instead of `docker run -it --mount type=bind,source=D:/Java/service/docker/config,target=/home/app services` changes it to `docker run -it --mount type=bind,source=D:/Java/service/docker/config/app.config,target=/home/app services` which made service to load and work